# How to configure axis on pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots

How to configure axis on pgfplots? Similar for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
%x axis
\draw[->] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node[below] {$x$};
\foreach \x in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {\footnotesize $\x$};
%y axis
\draw[->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node[left] {$y$};
\foreach \y in {-4,...,-1,1,2,...,4}
\draw[shift={(0,\y)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) node[left] {\footnotesize $\y$};
\node[below left] at (0,0) {\footnotesize $0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you mean by "configure"? Do you want to have different labels than numeric values? Do you want to modify the spacing between elements? Or both? Do you want to modify the format of the labels? Do you want to modify the format of the ticks? Or both? Do you want to change the arrows on the axis? Do you want to add arrows? Or both?

Comment: Do you mean something like the plot on page 169 of the version 1.5 manual for sine?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5]
\addplot [mark=none,domain=-4:4] {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RegisdaSilva We could still do with the question being clearer, for future users.

Comment: You could also write `axis lines=center` to avoid specifying both axes.