# Position some yticks to the right, and some others, to the left

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, ticks

I am trying to position the yticks to the left and right of the axis, depending on a comparaion to a reference value. Say in the following plot, I want to position the positive ylabels to the left, and the negatives ones to the right of the axis.
[image]

The code is as follows (and it is token from a previous [poste](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31391/how-to-configure-axis-on-pgfplots))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would such a design not interfere with the ticks on the negative axis and the negative numbers?

Comment: No, I can iterate. the point is that my plot is in the second and fourth quarters. So I want to move the positve yticks to the right of the y axis, and the positive xticks above the xaxis

Comment: I am confused: In your question you wanted to shift the positive values to the left (where they usually are) and the negative labels to the right of the axis -- now it is the other way round?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\begin{axis}[
  axis x line=center,
  axis y line=center,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={0,1,...,5},
  xlabel={$x$},
  ylabel={$y$},
  xlabel style={below right},
  ylabel style={above left},
  xmin=-5.5,
  xmax=5.5,
  ymin=-5.5,
  ymax=5.5,
  extra y ticks={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1},
  extra y tick style={yticklabel style={xshift=0.5ex, anchor=west}}
  ]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

however, as commented above, the tick labels will interefere

Comment: Thnaks, That was exactly what I was looking for